# My query cannot update into database after using function substr()

Tags: php, mysql

not sure why, after i'm using function substr() i cannot update my value to database, when i check in database no value(blank).

```
$result = '000603040000000000GL17KWJ10881011215000000000100';
$invoice = substr($result, 8, 20);  //output 0000000000GL17KWJ108

//update
$sql="UPDATE `order` SET invoice_pbb='$invoice' WHERE order_id=108";
$result=mysql_query($sql);  

if($result){
    echo "Successful";
}       
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

`column = invoice_pbb`
`type = varchar (100)`

*if i change the value with hardcode , i can update(not sure why).

```
$invoice = '0000000000GL17KWJ108';
```

*i'm using https

Thank if you can help me.

Comment: `if (!$result) die(mysql_error());` - Does that show anything?

Comment: please show the error. Use @deceze 's method to do so

Comment: What is the column *invoice_pbb* value after the query is run?

Comment: echo `$sql` and run it in your MySQL gui. your answer is there.

Comment: should insert this value 0000000000GL17KWJ108

Comment: how you tried what was suggested above?

Comment: @jared this output when i run $sql UPDATE `order` SET invoice_pbb='' WHERE order_id=108

Comment: @tradyblix yes , and mysite also running in https

Comment: then echo `$invoice` above the `$sql =` line, is it still `''`?

Comment: i tried your code and echoed `$sql` and got `UPDATE \`order\` SET invoice_pbb='0000000000GL17KWJ108' WHERE order_id=108`, not sure what's wrong there on your end

Comment: Does the row with OrderID 108 exist in the database?

Comment: @toby yes, the problem when i try insert value from substr() function

Comment: Try print_r($invoice); - it seems like substr is returning false, in which case you probably want to retitle, reword and retag your question, since that's nothing to do with mysql. If it *is* returning the right value then the only thing I can think of is some kind of weird encoding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i cannot see an obvious error in your code, but i don't know the context and maybe this steps can help finding the error.

First i would not reuse the variable $result, instead use a new variable. This avoids misunderstandings, if some code could be not executed.

```
$queryResult = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then it is better to check the result correctly, because `mysql_query()` can return mixed types. Note the === operator, you cannot reliably check the result with a simple if statement.

```
if ($queryResult === false)
  echo "ERROR";
else
  echo "Successful";
```

Then i would turn error reporting on, this may give you a hint about the actual problem.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Check what `$invoice` really contains before using it to do the query.

```
var_dump($invoice);
```

**Edit:**

Just one suggestion more, absolutely try to find another name for your table, using reserved words as tablename, is inviting trouble of all kind.

Comment: thanks, now i know what is wrong

Comment: @ruslyrossi - We are all curious what the problem was, could you shortly describe how you solved it, please?

Comment: all data come from form including invoice,credit card, etc then pass to bank and pass again to my website, the problem i forgot to send again form to get fresh data, i just refresh this page hope all data can update but i'm wrong..but for error_reporting(E_ALL);
all tell me not to use $result twice..now all working fine..sorry guy

Answer (score -1):

I think the above post was right.
$sql="UPDATE `order` SET invoice_pbb='".$invoice."' WHERE order_id=108";

because variable name in single quotes will not render any value because it reads character by characer.

Or,

you can check datatype,lengths etc in database

Comment: ... double quoted strings are designed to read any variable placed inside. that won't change anything at all.

Comment: @Shelim sorry still cannot, do you think this problem because value come from substr() function ? when i try with $invoice = '0000000000GL17KWJ108';   no problem database will update.

Comment: Also, you removed the ticks around 'order' so you'd probably get a syntax error as well.

Comment: may i know data type used for this field ?

Comment: @Braiba without ticks also allowed in mysql.ticks `` are used only for security reason like mysql injections

Comment: i'm using tick `` because i'm refer to mysql reserved words.

Comment: @Shelim Ekbal as ruslyrossi says, ticks *are* required around reserved words. They're also required to refer to column names that contain certain symbols, such as hyphens.